# Python 3.4 tkinter sleep

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to show all products within

```
itertools.product(string.punctuation, repeat=2))
```

from index 0 to end with sleep 0.5 sec after each element. Unfortunately tkinter hasn't normal sleep function. I can use only

```
w.after(time, callback)
```

but this is bad for what I want to do.

I want to do something like this:

```
t=0
for i in k:
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e1.insert(0,u[t])
    time.sleep(0.5)
    t+=1
```

It's my all code with first 3 products (I tried used functions for this, but too many functions are needed to show all products). Anyone have idea what should I do to make it work?

```
from tkinter import *
import itertools
import string

def d():
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e1.insert(0,u[1])

def y():
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e1.insert(0,u[2])

root = Tk()
l1 = Label(root, text="Current product:")
l1.pack(side = LEFT)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack(side = RIGHT)

k = list(''.join(c) for c in itertools.product(string.punctuation, repeat=2))
e=" "
u = e.join(k)
u = u.split(e)  
e1.insert(0,u[0])
e1.after(1000,d)
e1.after(2000,y)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is the purpose of sleeping? Are you aware your entire GUI becomes unresponsive when calling sleep?

Comment: It doesn't matter in my program. My program should only show next products at timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments via `after`:

```
def callback(product):
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e1.insert(0,product)

e1.after(1000,callback, u[1])
e1.after(2000,callback, u[2])
```

You can also do that in a loop:

```
for seconds, product in enumerate(k):
    e1.after(seconds*1000, callback, product)
```